# Routing inside a component

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a component that I use in a page and this component have tabs in it, the tabs works fine they aren't components though, they are just in the component.

This is what I'm trying to do, have a new link when clicking on a tab:

```
entity/someUid <-- Current behaviour

entity/someUid/messages   <-- When clicking on a tab
entity/someUid/languages  <-- When clicking on a tab
```

Page:

```js
<app-entity
  (currentTab)="getCurrentTab($event)"
></app-entity>
```

Page Module:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: EntityPage
  }
];
```

Page Component:

```js
// It does navigate like the example above but instead my 404 page is showing up
getCurrentTab(tab: string) {
  this.router.navigate(['entity', this.entity.uid, tab]);
}
```

The component itself:

```html
<ul>
  <li (click)="view = 'messages'; currentTab.emit('messages')">Messages</li>
  <li (click)="view = 'languages'; currentTab.emit('languages')">Languages</li>
</ul>

<div *ngIf="view == 'messages'">
  Messages Content
</div>

<div *ngIf="view == 'languages'">
  Languages Content
</div>
```

```js
@Output() currentTab: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

view: string
```

How can I make my component have routing while I still can render this component inside a page?

Comment: Have you declared all of your routes ? If the URL is right, then the component should be displayed

Comment: Could you create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) of what you have?

Comment: @Maryannah how can I declare all the routes?

Comment: By adding routes in your array of routes

Comment: As I said, create a small stackblitz app with what you have  and we can help

Comment: Do you have a route definition for in your routes.ts for `entity/:uid/messages`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/nested-routes/

Children routes by adding one more router outlet in app entity and make the routes declared in its module